# How can I hide object only from one 3d view

Tags: 3d-view

I am trying to hide object while animating it. But I have two view mode screen and I want one of them not be showing everyting including object. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layers!

Assuming you're using multiple windows and not just multiple views (view -> Duplicate Area into New Window) Select the object you want hidden, and hit "M"

select one of the boxes to move the object to - that's the other layer.

You can now click (single layer view) or shift+click (select multiple) the boxes on this guy :
[image]

and you will see the objects from only the selected layers.

Hint: the dot indicates that there are objects on the layer, the background tint means you're viewing the layer.

You can set one view to see all layers and another to view only one!

Comment: As of around 2.56 or so, you may need to click the "use scene layers instead of local layers" button next to the layers grid in order for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Update for 2.8+:

Just use Local Collection. First, put the objects you're going to hide in a collection.

[image]

Then check Local Collection on `N-Sidebar -> View`:

[image]

Now you can control the collection's visibility on a specific 3D Viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to local view in the view where you just want to show the current selected object. That way just the selected object is visible in this view. The item can be found in the View menu.